# React setState doesn't rerender on mobile only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Carousel component that renders different images based on the index that I pass into the component as a prop. That index is now currently being updated by passing a function that calls setState (declared in the parent component) into the onClick prop of the carousel arrows.

Everything works as expected on desktop (i.e. the images change on the click of the arrow), but that the rerender does not happen on mobile.

Here are the functions that I pass onto the onClick prop:

```
  slideNext = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const nextIndex = prevState.index + 1;
      return {
        index: (nextIndex === projects.length ? 0 : nextIndex)
      }
    });
  }

  slideBack = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const prevIndex = prevState.index - 1;
      return {
        index: (prevIndex <= 0 ? (projects.length - 1) : prevIndex)
      }
    });
  }
```

I debugged it, and the console is telling me that the functions `slideNext` and `slideBack` are being called, as well as the `setState` inside them.

I'm just not sure why `setState` rerenders the component as expected in desktop but not in mobile?

Comment: How are you debugging on mobile?  Is anything else different?  could projects.length be different? In Chrome desktop you can hit F12, then hit Ctrl + Shit + M and select Mobile from the device type drop-down.

Comment: What browser are you using on mobile?

Comment: @Safira Where is the `projects` defined? May be `this.projects` or `this.state.projects` ?  You might have getting an error on console.

Comment: @Madhavan.V projects is defined in the same file, outside of the component class. It doesn't seem like that's the problem because on desktop, it works fine.

Comment: @skellertor Safari and Chrome.

Comment: @Wyck yes, even when I used the code inspector in Chrome, it behaves differently when the dimensions are for mobile/responsive and when I turned it back to desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I've filled in some blanks with respect to `projects` to make a working example.  If this example does not reproduce your issue, then perhaps you can adjust my example to help me reproduce your problem.  Meanwhile: here's something that uses something similar to your code, and renders just fine on mobile.

Incidentally, I noticed that your logic for going to the previous index was wrong (you used `<= 0` when you should have written `< 0`)

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {
       projects: ['first', 'second', 'third'],
       index: 0
     };
  }
  
  render() {
    var slideNext = () => {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        const nextIndex = prevState.index + 1;
        return {
          index: (nextIndex === prevState.projects.length ? 0 : nextIndex)
        }
      });
    }

    var slideBack = () => {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        const prevIndex = prevState.index - 1;
        return {
          index: (prevIndex < 0 ? (prevState.projects.length - 1) : prevIndex)
        }
      });
    }  
    
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={slideBack}>Back</button>
        <button onClick={slideNext}>Next</button>
        <p>
          Index: <span>{this.state.index}</span>
        </p>
        <p>
          Project: <span>{this.state.projects[this.state.index]}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}

// Render
ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```